# Сохранение правки вопроса c позже объединёнными метками проваливается из-за ошибки сервера

Tags: дефект, метки, синонимы-меток, правки

Не могу отредактировать [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/307091/23044) из под своего пользователя. При попытке сохранить возникает ошибка сервера (http 500). Редактирование как анонимный пользователь [сработало](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/307091/timeline).

Похоже проблема в том, что из под своего пользователя я вижу метку `[файлы]` у вопроса, а при попытке редактирования как анонимный пользователь, метки показаны как `[files]` и `[file]` ([синонимы метки `[файлы]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B/synonyms)). По-видимому вопрос был создан с двумя метками, когда они ещё не были объединены.

Аналогично, для других [подобных вопросов](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/625042/questions-with-tag1-and-tag2-before-date20150401?tag1=file&tag2=files&date=20150401).

Comment: Как раз проявляется дефект, описанный в другом [вопросе](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4681/176217).

Comment: Да, вижу [tag:file] и [tag:files].